# Package a Samsung Smart TV app without the Samsung IDE or Eclipse plugin?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to build & deploy a Samsung SmartTV app without the IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766653/how-to-build-deploy-a-samsung-smarttv-app-without-the-ide)

Is there a way to package a Smart TV app without using the Samsung IDE tools - ideally I'd like to integrate the build into either an Ant or Grunt.js build script.

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I hadn't considered it before, but it could save me quite a bit of frustration in the long term to generate packages programatically.

Comment: @Quentin: In that case, you might be interested in my answer to the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just zip files containing the application, so long as you put the right files inside (which you can see examples of in the IDE's display, or by unzipping a package created with the IDE) there is no obvious reason that you would need to use the IDE.