# How to get Samsung Smart TV Emulator to see my app?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I'm just getting started on Samsung Smart TV development, and so far my first baby step has been a big failure.

I am running Linux, and because I already have Eclipse installed and configured for Android development, I haven't had success in getting the Smart TV SDK installed and working. However, encouraged by [How to build & deploy a Samsung SmartTV app without the IDE (e.g: on Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766653/how-to-build-deploy-a-samsung-smarttv-app-without-the-ide-e-g-on-linux), I have decided to go forward without it.

I do have the VirtualBox emulator running, however. So right now, I have built a basic app from the example here:

http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_2/getting_started/coding_js.html

And would like to see if I can just get it to start up on my emulator.

If I understand correctly, I need to take the directory structure of my app (with config.xml, index.html, and the Resources, JavaScript and CSS folders), package it into a .zip, and drop it in the "Apps" folder I have shared with the emulator. But when I do that, if I go to the emulator, refresh it, and hit "Open App", I am presented with an empty App list.

I know that the emulator is seeing the Apps folder, because if I put a subdirectory in it, then that directory shows in the Apps list in the emulator. But it's not showing the .zip file for my app.

I have been scouring the web for any useful information, but all tutorials just say something along the lines of "now test the app in your emulator to make sure it works. Now on to deployment...". Nobody gives any information on *how* to test the app in the emulator.

Can someone please shine some light on this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unzip your app in the app folder it should look like this

Samsung TV SDK 4\apps\yourapp\index.html

Samsung TV SDK 4\apps\yourapp\config.xml

Samsung TV SDK 4\apps\yourapp\other files and folders

Comment: You are absolutely correct. This was the solution. The sad thing is, I tried this early on and it didn't work, so I assumed it was wrong. But it turns out there was a typo in my config.xml (a missing space) that was causing a parsing error, and instead of giving me an error message, it just failed silently. The only reason I knew something was wrong was because I accidentally discovered how to crash the emulator's UI (by hitting the "Maximize" button), and when that happened, I was dumped to the Ubuntu command line and saw the error log.

Anyway, thank you for your help!