# Samsung Smart TV - upload application on tv for testing

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I wrote simple app for Samsung Smart TV and now I want to upload it to TV for testing purposes. According to this article http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00013/index.html everything seems to be very easy but in my IDE I can't find "Samsung Smart TV" menu. I've also heve not found button responsible for packaging app. Any help? I've downloaded the newest IDE from samsung web site.

Comment: What IDE version/OS and other information that you can share?

Comment: As I wrote I used the newest IDE (5.0 Beta). I'm working on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found how to package app using eclipse but I used this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/13840964/2069368 and it works. All I've done was to zip application, put it in apache www dir and create widgetlist.xml.

Answer (score 1):

It seems SDK 5.0 beta removing that magic menu, that's bad decision because that's the best shortcut to do everything for TV Apps Development.

To package the application you can do this:

1. Right Click on Your Project
2. Click "Export"
3. Expand the "Samsung Smart TV Apps"
4. Click "Package file" and Finish

The usual packaging window will show.

To setup the packaging/SDK configuration is:

1. Open "Window" menu bar --> "Preferences"
2. Expand the "Samsung Smart TV" menu and usual configuration window available there