# Samsung SDK: how to install app through apache server and view logs in console?

Tags: console.log, samsung-smart-tv

I am a beginner in Samsung SDK, havnt even used it for over 24 hours. I want to test an app on a Samsung Samrt TV and see the calls/Logs in the Console. I am using Mac OS. I have downloaded Samsung Smart TV SDK and ready to go. However I am having issues with the Apache Server and installing the app through it. Please advice with detailed steps. It will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through this post, It has answer to your query although in title it is mentioned for linux, But please read whole answer as it contains all the info and can be useful to you

[How to build & deploy a Samsung SmartTV app without the IDE (e.g: on Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766653/how-to-build-deploy-a-samsung-smarttv-app-without-the-ide-e-g-on-linux)